# C# XML Changing root name for sitemap by urlset

Tags: c#, xml, sitemap

I am manually generating a sitemap for my website.
I serialise an url list of my url, that's working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfUrl>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.mywebsite</loc>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
    <lastmod>2015-10-5</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.mywebsite/2</loc>
    <priority>0.80</priority>
    <lastmod>2015-10-13</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </url>
</ArrayOfUrl>
```

I try to change ArrayOfUrl by urlset adding [XmlRoot("urlset")] on my class but nothing is changing. Do you have any suggestions to make this properly?
There is my code:

```
    Database1 db = new Database1();
    public void WriteXML(Item modelItem)
    {
        using (db = new Database1())
        {
            string pathxml = string.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") );

            try
            {
                GoogleSiteMap google = new GoogleSiteMap();
                List<url> lsu = new List<url>();
                StreamWriter xmlfile;
                // Get List Item ON
                List<Item> ListItemActif = (db.Item.Where...

                foreach (Item i in ListItemActif)
                {
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(c.date_creation_Item);
                    string datecreation = dt.Year + "-" + dt.Month + "-" + dt.Day;

                    url u = new url();
                    u.Location = string.Concat("mysite.com/" + c.url_Item);
                    u.LastModified = datecreation;
                    u.ChangeFrequency = "daily";
                    u.Priority = "0.80";
                    lsu.Add(u);
                }
                google.Urls = lsu;
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathxml))
                {
                    // Créer fichier
                    // Authorisation d'accès
                    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity access = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(pathxml);
                    xmlfile = File.CreateText(pathxml + "Content/xml/sitemap-kub.xml");

                    XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(google.Urls.GetType());

                    XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    xmlNameSpace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                    xmlNameSpace.Add("schemaLocation", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd");
                    xmlNameSpace.Add("", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

                    writer.Serialize(xmlfile, google.Urls, xmlNameSpace);
                    xmlfile.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = "Message :" + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("urlset")]
    public class GoogleSiteMap
    {
        public List<url> Urls { get; set; }
    }

    public class url
    {
        [XmlElement("loc")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("priority")]
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("lastmod")]
        public string LastModified { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("changefreq")]
        public string ChangeFrequency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the C# code that generates the XML?

Comment: An xml file can have only one root tag.  Performing an add would create a 2nd root tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should look something like the following:

```
[XmlRoot("urlset")] // or [XmlType("urlset")]
public class UrlSet : List<Url>
{

}

[XmlType("url")]
public class Url
{
    public string loc;
    public decimal priority;
    public string lastmod;
    public string changefreq;
}
```

There are several other ways to handle this kind of scenario, but this would make the most sense to me.

Comment: I tied to just add XmlType as I already tried xmlroot but nothing is changing. thanks anyway

Comment: Your classes won't work the way you expect them to - change `GoogleSiteMap` to the following: `public class GoogleSiteMap : List<url> { }`.  The serializer is going to expect there to be an element for the class and an element for all class members - which will introduce an additional node between root and your children that you don't want.

Comment: Try to create the class in C# and then `Serialize()` it to see what I mean